# Enabling Platform Encryption on two packages

Tags: security, isv, encryption, platform-encryption

We have two managed packages and one is the base package for the other and contains all the fields (no fields on the second package). We want to enable platform encryption on the fields of the base package. I was reading documentation and came across the following text [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/ISVPlatformEncryption#What_is_Shield_Platform_Encryption.3F):

> Note that we strongly recommend you have only one package with Platform Encryption. Otherwise, in addition to having two packages (two contracts, two security reviews to pass, etc.) you would not be able to support a customer just having subscribed to Platform Encryption without uninstalling a package an reinstalling the other. A nightmare for your customer as well as for you!

Can someone clarify:

1- Why would the ISV need to uninstall and reinstall to enable encryption?As I understand it, it involves encrypting fields after packages are installed.

2- if this would apply to us (given that we only have one package with fields and the other only looks up to the base package fields)

Comment: If your base package does not hold any data then it should be fine.

Comment: It has all the custom objects and fields and all the data. The package that refers to it does not have any data

Comment: If base package is installed in subscriber org and does not contain any data and platform encryption is enabled. You can install your extension package without base package uninstall.

Comment: Did you find answer to your question or did you contact the Salesforce support